# Не работает выпадающее меню bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

CSS и js загружаются однако не работают выпадающие пункты меню, не могу понять почему.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="windows-1251">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" href="/images/logo.png">
        <title><?= $title ?></title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Пример</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Вкладка 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Вкладка 2</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Вкладка 3<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Вкладка 4<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Вкладка 5<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/main/about">Вкладка 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/auth">Вкладка 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <?= $content ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Все работает с библиотеками с cdn. Может все же что-то с локальными скриптами?

Comment: Запустил в codepen все работает. https://codepen.io/shoonia/pen/VGPOQO?editors=1011